# option:checked is not working with IE 11

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have select tag and need to change background image of option based on selection. I am using style below, This style works with chrome but not working with IE 11. Not sure what changes I need to do to make it work on IE 11 ?

```
          option:checked 
          {    
                       background-image: url("SelectBlue.png");
                       color: white;
          }
```

Full HTML Code below

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <title>change demo</title>
              <style>
              div {
                color: red;
              }
              </style>


            <style type="text/css"> 

                select::-ms-expand
                {
                    display:none;       
                }   
                .ListBox{       
                    background-color: transparent;
                    font-family: verdana;
                    font-size: 8pt;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: black;
                    vertical-align:middle;  
                    height:400px;
                    width:300px;
                }

                option:checked {    
                    background-image: url("DataGridSelectBlue.png");
                    color: white;
                }   

            </style>

              <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>

             <input  id="hid"  type="hidden">
            <select id="sweets" name="sweets" multiple="multiple" class="ListBox">
              <option value="a">Chocolate</option>
              <option value="b" selected="selected">Candy</option>
              <option value="c">Taffy</option>
              <option value="d" selected="selected">Caramel</option>
              <option value="e">Fudge</option>
              <option value="f"> Cookie</option>
            </select>

            <select name="food" multiple="multiple" class="ListBox">
              <option>Idly</option>
              <option selected="selected">Sambar</option>
              <option>Dosa</option>
              <option selected="selected">Bisibele bhath</option>
              <option>chutney</option>
              <option>upma</option>
            </select>

            <div></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: can you share your html code as well please?

Comment: it seems that there's no full support for modifying the color/background of a checked option, but there are still properties you can modify - like "border": http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWAmjK

Comment: What could be other option other thank option:checked ?

Comment: You can use JS to change the class of the checked option and then use the class selector instead the pseudo-class selector. But as mentioned in the answer - the problem is that the css property isn't fully compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deeper research

According to MDN the :checked CSS pseudo-class selector (basic feature) is compatible to IE11:

- Chrome 1.0
- Firefox (Gecko) 1.0
- Internet Explorer 9.0
- Opera 9.0
- Safari 3.1

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked

If so, the reason it might not work is that the property 'background-image' isn't fully browser-compatible.

I'm using chrome and have created the following codepen (based on your code) - you can test it on several browsers to see which property is being supported:

```
            option:checked {    
                background-color: green; /*Won't apply*/
                color: green; /*Won't apply*/
                border:1px solid green; /*Will apply (at least on chrome)*/
                background-image:url('http://www.bostonscientific.com/content/dam/bostonscientific/utility-icons/icon_Phone.png'); /*Will apply (at least on chrome)*/
            }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWAmjK